# Center text over a flex element

Tags: css, flexbox

I am trying to build a custom stepper with CSS and I am hitting a wall to center the label on top of each step.

I've build a quick and simplified version of my current implementation :

```css
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
}

.circle-wrapper {
  flex: 1;
}

.circle-wrapper.active>.circle {
  background-color: #3490DC;
  transform: scaleX(1.2) scaleY(1.2)
}

.circle-wrapper.complete>.circle {
  background-color: #38C172;
}

.circle {
  width: 34px;
  height: 34px;
  background-color: #B8C2CC;
  border-radius: 100%;
}

.label {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.wrapper> :last-child {
  flex: none;
}

.line {
  height: 4px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #1F9D55;
  position: relative;
  bottom: 19px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="circle-wrapper complete">
    <div class="label">Label 1</div>
    <div class="circle"></div>
    <div class="line"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="circle-wrapper active">
    <div class="label">Label 2 with a longer name</div>
    <div class="circle"></div>
    <div class="line"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="circle-wrapper">
    <div class="label">Label 3</div>
    <div class="circle"></div>
    <div class="line"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="circle-wrapper">
    <div class="label">Label 4</div>
    <div class="circle"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[You can see it here in this codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/MqMEea)

So far so good, but I want to center the label over the circle div without impacting the flex size between each circle and I can't manage to do it.

Any advice ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a `left` and a `transform` to move it into the centre:

```css
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
}

.circle-wrapper {
  flex: 1;
  position:relative;
}

.circle-wrapper.active>.circle {
  background-color: #3490DC;
  transform: scaleX(1.2) scaleY(1.2)
}

.circle-wrapper.complete>.circle {
  background-color: #38C172;
}

.circle {
  width: 34px;
  height: 34px;
  background-color: #B8C2CC;
  border-radius: 100%;
}

.label {
  position:relative;
  left: 17px;                   /* move left 17px (half of circle width) */
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  transform: translateX(-50%);  /* move it backwards 50% of itself */
  text-align: center;           /* align text in centre */
}

.wrapper> :last-child {
  flex: none;
}

.line {
  height: 4px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #1F9D55;
  position: relative;
  bottom: 19px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="circle-wrapper complete">
    <div class="label">Label 1</div>
    <div class="circle"></div>
    <div class="line"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="circle-wrapper active">
    <div class="label">Label 2 with a longer name</div>
    <div class="circle"></div>
    <div class="line"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="circle-wrapper">
    <div class="label">Label 3</div>
    <div class="circle"></div>
    <div class="line"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="circle-wrapper">
    <div class="label">Label 4</div>
    <div class="circle"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: That would works for me but how well is the calc supported ? I see in https://caniuse.com/#feat=calc that it's supposed to work in every browser (almost) but it has a few known issues.

Comment: That's perfect ! This is exactly what I needed, thanks a lot !

Answer (score 1):

If you want to center it always above the circle, I would use the following: put the label inside the circle and use the following CSS properties:

```css
.circle {
  position: relative;
  width: 34px;
  height: 34px;
  background-color: #B8C2CC;
  border-radius: 100%;
  margin: 50px 100px; /* remove this */
}

.circle .label {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  bottom: 100%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<div class="circle">
  <div class="label">Small One</div>
</div>
<div class="circle">
  <div class="label">Very long label with long text</div>
</div>
```

The percentage values of `left` and `bottom` reference to the width of the parent element and the percentage value of `transform: translate` references to the element's size. This allows you to position it in the center of the parent with `left: 50%` and then moving it to the left again by the half of the width of the element itself.

Comment: Your solutions works as well, but Pete's solution doesn't involve updating my current template ! Thanks anyway !